# Deleting tableview cells won't update index

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have a UITableview with multiple delete functionality. When a user selects on a cell ie; row 5. It deletes that row, and every row prior (0...5). Whilst in theory this works correctly. The index path of the rows do not update when calling `tableView.deleteRows(at:)` within `beginUpdates` & `endUpdates`.

One work around involves calling either `reloadSections` or `reloadData` however this yields
unwanted behaviour since it prematurely ends the `deleteRows` animation. And/or doing so after a delay. (ie below)

```
DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 0.25) {
   tableView.reloadSections(IndexSet(integer: 0), with: .none)
}
```

```
tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
tableView.beginUpdates()
var allIndexPaths = [IndexPath]()
for index in 0...indexPath.row {
    allIndexPaths.append(.init(row: index, section: 0))
}
self.tableData.removeSubrange(0...indexPath.row)
tableView.deleteRows(at: allIndexPaths, with: .fade)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

I created a test app to display this issue.

[image]
[image]

Scrolling down, and up again fixes this issue. So it is obviously a dequeuing issue.

Comment: Why have you bracketed the delete in `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` ?  You shouldn't need that for a single delete operation (even one that involves multiple rows.

Comment: @Paulw11 It was my understanding that for a deletion of anything more than one row it was needed. Despite that; wether the code is within `beginUpdates`/`endUpdates` makes no difference.

Comment: Can you provide a more complete [MCVE]?  I just used your code in a playground and it worked perfectly

Comment: @Paulw11 https://github.com/Harryjeffs/scaling-waffle contains the test code. Do your indexes update? Theres a bunch of other test code, for this example, in the repo.

Comment: OK, I understand what you are expecting to see now that I have run your code.  Your code does exactly what I expect and what you have asked it to do.  What you are expecting is that the "new" row 0 cell will say "row 0" instead of "row 6".  This isn't going to happen unless you reload the tableview or at least reload the visible rows.  The "Row 0" is just text in the cell. The tableview doesn't "know" that it contains the row index.  The row number should really be immaterial; it is just an internal implementation detail.

Answer (score 1):

Your code works as expected.  The "row 0" text is just that; text in a label. There is no dynamic binding between the row index and that label's text.

The only way you are going to see the row numbers update is if you explicitly reload the visible rows.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let allIndexPaths = (0...indexPath.row).map { IndexPath(row:$0, section:0) }
    self.tableData.removeFirst(indexPath.row+1)
    tableView.deleteRows(at: allIndexPaths, with: .fade)
        
    tableView.reloadRows(at: self.tableView.indexPathsForVisibleRows ?? [], with: .none)
}
```

Generally you wouldn't expose the row numbers to the user; they are just an implementation detail.

Comment: Sorry if I echo some of these concepts in my answer. I just wanted to expand on the idea.

Answer (score 1):

Actually what you are expecting is exactly the opposite of what you should expect. You've misapprehended the purpose of batch updates. The idea here is that the user is deleting the cell *and its corresponding data.* The table view is just a presentation *of the data*.

Moreover, cells are reused. So they need to be kept tied to the data they represent. Cells do not represent the *row* they happen to be in at that moment; they represent the *data* corresponding to that row. When cells are deleted, the corresponding data is deleted, and so the *correspondence keeps working* between all the rest of the cells and the data.

To illustrate, forget about rows for a moment and think only about *numbers*. It may be that the cell in row 0 was associated with the data "0" to *start* with; but if the user *deletes* that row, what should happen is that that cell *and the "0"* are gone! That is what the user was trying to do: by *way* of the table, the user removes the *data*, which in this case is the "0".

So now there is no "0" in the data. And the "0" must not magically return from the dead. But that is exactly what you try to make it do. And so the results are incoherent.

The error in your code, then, is that after the deletion you then proceed to make the data rise from the dead, by trying to reassociate the cells with the row number they happen to occupy now. No. The cell needs to be associated consistently with a piece of data.

So, in your `resetData`, change the key line populating the cell to this:

```
textLabel?.text = "Piece of data: \(data.index)"
```

Suddenly the correct and expected behavior of the table view will spring to life — simply because you have let go of the misapprehension that a cell represents the *index number* of the row it happens to be in at the moment. It doesn't. It represents the *data* at that index number.

Data is user-facing. Index numbers are not. And now you see what trouble you can get into by trying to make index number be user-facing! Distinguish between *model* and *view* and all will be well. The view shows the user the *model* — it does not show the user facts about itself. View is not model; data is not stored in the interface, but in some sort of internal data storage. That, in fact, is exactly *why* table views have a data source.

Answer (score 0):

Use `performBatchUpdates` instead.

beginUpdates/endUpdates sometimes doesn't work somehow.

---Update---

I ran the project you provided on Github.
It worked well, I didn't see the problems you mentioned.
So I can only guess, this happened base on the devices, especially for the simulators.

Try to put these codes bellow `endUpdates` to refresh the UI of tableview:

```
tableView.setNeedsUpdateConstraints()
tableView.needsUpdateConstraints()
tableView.setNeedsLayout()
tableView.layoutIfNeeded()
tableView.superview.setNeedsLayout()
tableView.superview.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Comment: Doesn't technically solve the problem. The indexPaths aren't updated.

Comment: There is a general misunderstanding about `beginUpdates/endUpdates` and also `performBatchUpdates`. Both APIs are for **multiple simutaneous** insert/delete/move operations. They have no effect for a single delete operation like in the question. And please explain what the 6 lines of code actually do and how they are related to update the **content** of the cell